# Как создать класс, если имя его приходит строкой?

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть у меня различные классы: `Test`, `Conf`, `Stat` и тд...

Мне приходит строка `'test' или 'conf' ... 'strN'`

Как мне создать экземпляр класса?

```
class Test{
  constructor(){
    this.a = 1;
  }
}
const class_name = 'Test';
const _class = new class_name() //не работает, так как говорит строка не функция
const __class = eval(`new ${class_name}()`) // работает, но такой подход мне не нравится
```

в PHP так работает, а вот в JS что-то пока не нашел варианта как реализовать такое.

P.S. есть вариант использовать `eval()`, но чет не вызывает доверия

Comment: `if( class_name === 'test') _class = new Test();`

Comment: Кстати, `new (eval(class_name))()` удобнее, чем ``eval(`new ${class_name}()`)``.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin да, это вариант - но представь что их может быть сотня...будет лапшекод)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
class Test { constructor() { this.x = 1 } }
class Conf { constructor() { this.x = 2 } }
class Stat { constructor() { this.x = 3 } }

var map = {
  test: Test,
  conf: Conf,
  stat: Stat,
}

var name = 'conf'
var obj = new map[name]()
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Странно, что нельзя создать класс из строки..

Comment: @doox911, ничего странного.